# osgi.dev Property in eclipse 4.5

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

We are using osgi within a jboss eap server. In development, we reference the workspace plugins in the config.ini. We also used the **osgi.dev** in config.ini property to add our classes folder (target/classes) to the classpath. This **worked fine in eclipse 4.3**.

**In eclipse 4.5.2** the this property seems to have **no effect anymore**. Was this removed in 4.5(.2), is there another way to tell the BundleClassloader where to find the class files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution in the [eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1077795&goto=1733265&#msg_1733265). The reason of this behavior is likely the bug described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446571).